# Rebol - generate excel with image

Tags: excel, rebol

I found an example how to generate excel file with rebol. But I need to put an image in the excel file. But there's nothing about how to do that...

```
data: [ <table border="1"><tr><th width="100"> "State" </th><th width="100">"Jan"</th><th width="100">"Feb"</th><th width="100">"Mar"</th><th width="100">"Total"</th></tr><tr><td> "QLD" </td><td> 400.00 </td><td> 500.00 </td><td> 600.00 </td><td> "=szum(B2:D2)" </td></tr><tr><td> "NSW" </td><td> 430.00 </td><td> 660.00 </td><td> 600.00 </td><td> "=szum(B3:D3)" </td></tr><tr><td> "VIC" </td><td> 200.00 </td><td> 300.00 </td><td> 900.00           </td><td> "=szum(B4:D4)" </td></tr><tr><td colspan="5"></td></tr><tr><th></th><th>"=szum(B2:B4)"</th><th>"=szum(C2:C4)"</th><th>"=szum(D2:D4)"</th><th>"=szum(E2:E4)"</th></tr><tr><td colspan="5"> "image here" </td></tr></table> ]        
    write %demo.xls data
```

Answer (score 2):

As this looks like plain HTML, adding just `<IMG SRC="your_image">` should be enough e.g.

```
 <table border="1">
 <tr><th width="100"> "State" </th><th width="100">"Jan"</th><th width="100">"Feb"</th><th width="100">"Mar"</th><th width="100">"Total"</th></tr><tr><td> "QLD" </td><td> 400.00 </td><td> 500.00 </td><td> 600.00 </td><td> "=szum(B2:D2)" </td></tr><tr><td> "NSW" </td><td> 430.00 </td><td> 660.00 </td><td> 600.00 </td><td> "=szum(B3:D3)" </td></tr><tr><td> "VIC" </td><td> 200.00 </td><td> 300.00 </td><td> 900.00           </td><td> "=szum(B4:D4)" </td></tr><tr><td colspan="5"></td></tr><tr><th></th><th>"=szum(B2:B4)"</th><th>"=szum(C2:C4)"</th><th>"=szum(D2:D4)"</th><th>"=szum(E2:E4)"</th></tr><tr><td colspan="5">
 <IMG SRC="demo-b_html_cf8b9660.png" WIDTH=616 HEIGHT=772 HSPACE=37 VSPACE=28>
 </td></tr></table>
```

[image: demo.jpg]